# Viewing website on iPhone - Sizing Issue

Tags: iphone, css, zooming, crop

I'm hoping there's a relatively simple fix for this.  I've created a simple website for a client which displays as expected in all browsers.  Developing a separate mobile site for the project was not part of the scope of work, but I would expect the website to display correctly on modern mobile browsers.  Currently, on an iPhone 4, the left side of the 1000px-wide container is clipped (by maybe 10px), and I can't scroll left to see it at all.  I'm wondering if this is a CSS issue or some kind of zoom issue?  The site can be visited [here](http://jessehindle.com/wordpress).

I've had a hard time finding any resources related to the problem, but did find this snippet:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.9;">
```

Could this be the start of a work-around? I would be happy if the site loaded with a default zoom of, say, 75%, but I have no experience coding for mobile devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for my particular case, I have found a solution that works.  Hopefully this will be helpful for others in similar situations.

The key was, in fact, in the viewport meta-tag.  I'm working with a webpage whose content is restricted to a centered 1000px x 600px container.  [THIS](http://www.sitepoint.com/iphone-development-12-tips/) article was extremely helpful in figuring this out.

As the article states, "By default, Safari on the iPhone will render your page as if it was a desktop browser on a big screen, with 980 pixels width available for the web content. Then it will scale down the content so that it fits the small screen."

In my case, with a 1000px fixed width, I was left with 20px cropped off the left, and an inability to pan over to it.  The trick is to set a custom width (and height if necessary).
Be sure to check the site in both vertical and horizontal iPhone orientations.  There are other parameters you can  use with this meta-tag, but I've kept it simple.

This is the code I included between the `<head></head>` tags of the site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1050px, height=650px" />
```

This gives me a 25px white border around the content of the site, and still allows zooming, etc.  This is NOT a substitute for an iPhone specific website, but it ensures that users will be able to access all of the site's content.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the initial scale.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;">
```

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have an iphone with me right now.  Is this the typical way to fit content to mobile devices without a separate stylesheet?

Comment: alright, i've tried that out, but it didn't yeild good results.  As the site stands, when the iPhone is vertical, a small amount of the left side is cut off.  When the phone is horizontal, header and footer are cut off.  With the code above implemented, there is no zooming ability and only a small portion of the site is showing. I'll continue researching this meta-tag to get a better grasp of it.  Any other help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter some CSS for mobile view, there's a tool named [adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/) for this use. It chooses the stylesheet related to the screen resolution.

Comment: @tpaksu...this isn't exactly what I'm looking for in this situation, but having skimmed the documentation, it seems like an awesome tool.  I'll definitely be using it in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking that you can copy-paste your current css code with body element defined with 10px right margin or something, then use this adapt.js tool to switch between those css files.